# Extract Text From same class name(Python web scraping)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm beginner in Python Webscriping using beautifulsoup. I was trying to scrape one real estate website using beautifulsoup but there is row with different information in each column. However each column's class name is same so When I trying to scrape information of each column, I got a same result becuase of same class name.

[Link](https://housing.com/in/buy/search?f=eyJiYXNlIjpbeyJ0eXBlIjoiUE9MWSIsInV1aWQiOiJhMWE1MjFmYjUzNDdjYTAxNWZlNyIsImxhYmVsIjoiQWhtZWRhYmFkIn1dLCJub25CYXNlQ291bnQiOjAsImV4cGVjdGVkUXVlcnkiOiIlMjBBaG1lZGFiYWQiLCJxdWVyeSI6IiBBaG1lZGFiYWQiLCJ2IjoyLCJzIjoiZCJ9) of the website I was trying to scrape.

Code From The HTML

```
<div class="lst-middle-section resale">
<div class="item-datapoint va-middle">
    <div class="lst-sub-title stub text-ellipsis">Built Up Area</div>
    <div class="lst-sub-value stub text-ellipsis">2294 sq.ft.</div>
</div>
<div class="item-datapoint va-middle">
    <div class="lst-sub-title stub text-ellipsis">Avg. Price</div>
    <div class="lst-sub-value stub text-ellipsis"><i class="icon-rupee"></i> 6.5k / sq.ft.</div>
</div>
<div class="item-datapoint va-middle">
    <div class="lst-sub-title stub text-ellipsis">Possession Date</div>
    <div class="lst-sub-value stub text-ellipsis">31st Dec, 2020</div>
</div>
```

Code I Tried!

```
for item in all:
try:
    print(item.find('span', {'class': 'lst-price'}).getText())
    print(item.find('div',{'class': 'lst-heading'}).getText())
    print(item.find('div', {'class': 'item-datapoint va-middle'}).getText())
    print('')
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

If I use class 'item-datapoint va-middle' again then it shows sq.ft area not avg.price or Possession date.

Solution? TIA!

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried?

Comment: I edited a code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find_elements_by_class_name` instead of `find_element_by_class_name`.

```
find_elements_by_class_name("item-datapoint.va-middle")
```

You will get a list of elements.

[Selenium docs: Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

#### Edit:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://housing.com/in/buy/search?f=eyJiYXNlIjpbeyJ0eXBlIjoiUE9MWSIsInV1aWQiOiJhMWE1MjFmYjUzNDdjYT' \
      'AxNWZlNyIsImxhYmVsIjoiQWhtZWRhYmFkIn1dLCJub25CYXNlQ291bnQiOjAsImV4cGVjdGVkUXVlcnkiOiIlMjBBaG1lZGFiYWQiL' \
      'CJxdWVyeSI6IiBBaG1lZGFiYWQiLCJ2IjoyLCJzIjoiZCJ9'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
fields = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item-datapoint.va-middle")
for i, field in enumerate(fields):
    print(i, field.text)
driver.quit()
```

Now you see the index in the list (fields) for every element.

Print the elements you want like here:

```
poss_date = fields[2].text
```

Comment: Type Error: NoneType Object is not callable.

Comment: see edit for fix, replace spaces with dots in class name